# Two jQuery Delay Messages?

Tags: jquery

Here is our code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a#installfc').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        window.open("http://www.site.com/ads/tr.php?src=source",'_parent');    
        $(this).html("Opening Download Link.. Please wait").delay(3000).html("Please run the installer after downloading");
    });
});
</script>
```

Basically, we want the message to display, and then 3 seconds later it changes to another message.

What am I doing wrong?

~ jquery noob.

Comment: I believe that the delay only affects the animation queue, it's not a blocking call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ive only really seen `delay` used when doing jQuery animation effects. Its possible there is a way to use that  method to do what you want, but you could just as easily fall back to standard javascript `setTimeout`:

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/TMgPD/

```
$('a#installfc').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        window.open("http://www.site.com/ads/tr.php?src=source");    
        $this = $(this);
        $this.html("Opening Download Link.. Please wait")
        setTimeout(function(){
                    $this.html("Please run the installer after downloading")
        },3000);
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Use setTimeout instead. Delay only works on jQuery effect (e.g. slidUp, fadeIn):

```
    $(this).html("Opening Download Link.. Please wait");
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(this).html("Please run the installer after downloading");
    }, 3000);
```

Answer (score 1):

use setTimeOut function instead

Answer (score 0):

You can use *delay* and *queue* together to get the effect you want.

```
$(this).html("Text 1").delay(3000).queue(function(next) {
  $(this).html("Text 2");
  next();
});
```

In general, I think you'll want to stick to *setTimeout*, as that method gives you more control and is usually more appropriate.